Vietnam war movie
I'm trying to find a Vietnam war move. It was most likely back in the 80's when I saw this...but I'm not sure.
I remember parts of it only, there's an American soldier in it named Red. There's a big muscled up soldier there and in one place they come upon some tunnels and have some American tunnel rats come in and the big guy makes fun of them.
In another scene one of the soldiers is coming back to combat after being shot and has to lay-over until the next morning at a fire base and the guys there get him stoned out of his head and the next morning the put him on the chopper and send him in that way, he jumped off the chopper right in the middle of live combat.
In another scene an American solider that's half Chinese comes upon a Vietnam boy and when the boy sees him he looks at that solider and says you same, same me....and it makes him very mad at the boy.

Platoon - 1986
Starring Charlie Sheen, Tom Berringer and Willem Dafoe

Is set in the Vietnam War.
Has a character called Red played by John C McGinley (of Scrubs Fame) 
Willem Dafoe's character Sgt Elias goes into some Viet Cong tunnels
armed with a flashlight and a pistol, he finds a hospital here and kills some Viet Cong.
It also has a scene where they all get stoned





Johnny Depps character - Gator Lerner got injured in an ambush near a
church and was rescued by Charlie Sheen's character Taylor and
eventually medevaced away.

A main plot point of the film involves:

 Sgt Barnes played by Tom Berenger shooting Sgt Elias while on a mission and the NVA killing Sgt Elias because of this. This scene is set to the magnificent Adagio with Strings

The imdb link is here

platoon does not cover any of hints except for being a movie about vietnam war

@MarianPaździoch except for the character called red, the scene in the tunnels and the getting stoned
